# What's the Google MapTypeId for the 8-bit April Fools day?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The Google Maps 8-bit April Fools joke can still be accessed with the [`"t=8"` parameter](http://maps.google.com/maps?t=8).

You can even embed the map with the Quest in it by using the `<iframe>` embed option.

[Google Maps 8 bit embed http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2066483/google_map-8_bit.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2066483/google_map-8_bit.png)

But for those who already have maps that use the proper Maps V3 API, what is the correct [`MapTypedId`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId) for Quest mode? Obviously it isn't:

- `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADTYPE`
- `google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE`
- `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID`
- `google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN`

`google.maps.MapTypeId.QUEST` doesn't work. I wouldn't think the Quest would be available in the API, but after seeing it in the `<iframe>` I think maybe it could.

If you troll through the [obfuscated source code of the `<iframe>`](http://maps.google.com/?t=8&output=embed&ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=43.713406,68.466797), you can find an array of `[14534,"Quest"]`, but beyond that I'm at a loss in Google's obfuscated JavaScript. My guess is that finding this answer isn't for the light hearted, and it may not be available in the API at all.

Anyone?

Comment: google.maps.MapTypeId.QUEST is included in the Famicom cartridge.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blog.bn.ee/2012/03/31/how-to-use-google-maps-8-bit-tiles-in-your-own-project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i doubt that this is a real maptype,

check here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/-t3YmEBs_Co

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, but it's close enough. I'd like to have the button for "Quest" (or whatever), and this just overlays the tiles on top without the ability to toggle. It's probably as close as we're going to get. Thanks.

Comment: yeah i know, but i think there is something else that captures the full layer that should be toggleable: http://www.mapstd.com/ i didnt look up the code...maybe you can extract whats needed, bests!

Comment: Thanks for the clues! I pieced it together from these examples. You're right: There is (probably) no MapTypeId, but you set and register your own `ImageMapType` and add it as a member of `mapTypeIds` array. I created a public Gist for anyone who wants to add a Quest button to their maps. https://gist.github.com/2424961